# QWebPage segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, qwebpage

When I instantiate an QWebPage object I have a segmentation fault, I don't understand why !

I call my object in main.cpp

```
webview *nav = new webview();
```

my webview.h :

```
#ifndef WEBVIEW_H
#define WEBVIEW_H

#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QDebug>

#include "arguments.h"

class webview
{
public:
    webview();
    ~webview();
    bool load(Arguments *args);
    QWebFrame* getFrame() { return frame;}

private:
    QWebPage *page;
    QWebFrame *frame;
};
```

and my webview.cpp

```
#include "webview.h"
webview::webview()
{

    page = new QWebPage();
}
[...]
webview::~webview()
{
delete page;
}
```

An Segmentation fault error appear in webview constructor :

```
page = new QWebPage();
```

Really I don't understand why

you can download the project here : http://www.partage-facile.com/Y8NROQ09HG/htmltopdf.tar.gz.html

Comment: Is a backtrace available?

Comment: If you want more information you can download the project here : http://www.partage-facile.com/Y8NROQ09HG/htmltopdf.tar.gz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use QtWebKit with QCoreApplication, change all QCoreApplication to QApplication.

Answer (score 0):

if you really don't need to embed you page in a Widget (you don't set the *parent* of it) you can create the QWebPage on the stack.

[See the example in Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebpage.html#details)

Comment: I am on console application, I can't use widget

Comment: my problem is when instantiating the object, the doc does not provide an example for this

Comment: The example says to create the QWebPage on the stack