# QWebpage constructor segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qt5, qwebkit

My problem is supposedly very similar to [QWebPage segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119520) but none of the suggested solutions there help me.

I'm trying to run a unit test for a module of our console application that should render a web page to a PDF. As far as I understand the chapter [Using QWebPage in a Widget-less Environment](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebpage.html#using-qwebpage-in-a-widget-less-environment) this is what `QWebPage` is meant to be there for.

But still, the unit test segfaults inside the constructor of `QWebPage`.

```
class ReportingTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ReportingTest();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void initTestCase();

    void reportsCanBeGenerated();

    void cleanupTestCase();

private:
    QWebPage webPage;
};
```

Guessing from the call stack I would say, that it still tries to create widgets although it shouldn't:

```
0    WebKit::initializeWebKitWidgets()
1    ??
2    QWebPage::QWebPage(QObject*)
3    ReportingTest::ReportingTest   
4    main
```

I cannot use the other accepted answer and switch from `QCoreApplication` to `QApplication` as it is mandatory to run as a UI-less daemon.

The second question does not have an effect either, creating the object on the heap or on the stack produces the same error with the same call stack.